# Trignometric functions, Maximum value

Tags: trigonometry

$f(x)=\sin^{16}(x) +\cos^{18}(x)$,
find the maximum value of the given function $f(x)$.

I tried differentiating the given function however couldn't get the value of $x$ for which I could substitute the value in the given function so as to get the maximum value.
Please answer this query with detailed analysis 
thanking you in advance
sudhanshu singh

Answer (score 4):

Let $a = \sin^2x$, and $b = \cos^2x$, then $a + b = 1$, and $f(x) = f(a) = a^8 + b^9 = a^8 + (1-a)^9$, for $0 \leq a \leq 1$. You can find $f'(a)$, and set it equal to $0$ to continue.

Comment: It's important to note that $a$ can only take values in the range of $\sin^2 x$ so be careful to maximise $f$ only over $a\in[0, 1]$.

Comment: thanks for answering, the problem lies after equating to zero , after differentiating you get a polynomial function from where it is difficult to find the discreet value of a

Comment: The trick is to look at the behaviour of $f(a)$ in $[0, 1]$.
We take the second derivative, $f''(a) = 56a^6 + 72(1-a)^7$. Note that for $a\in (0, 1), f''(a)$ is positive. Therefore if there is a stationary point of $f$ in $(0, 1)$, it must be a local minimum.
Therefore, to find the maximum, we need to look at the boundaries. That is, $f(0) = f(1) = 1$. And that's it, the maximum must be 1.

Comment: is there any other way to arrive at the solution?

Comment: thanks Damien , thankyou so much

Answer (score 2):

As bounded functions, we have $ \ 0 \ \le \ \sin^{16} \ x \  \le \ 1 \ $ and $ \ 0 \ \le \ \cos^{18} \ x \ \le \ 1 \ $ .  The maximum for each function is located exactly at values of $ \ x \ $ where the other equals zero.  Moreover, the value of either function falls to less than $ \ \left( 0.9 \right)^{16} \ \approx \ 0.185 \ $  within 0.5 units of their individual maxima, which lie $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ \approx \ 1.57 \ $ units apart.  Midway between each maximum of $ \ f(x) \ $, either function is less than or equal to $ \ \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{16} \ = \ \frac{1}{2^8} \ $ .  Each function strictly decreases to either side of its maxima in proceeding to their minima. $ ^* $ So the sum of the two never exceeds 1.

$  * \ $ We will need to resort to calculus to show that the absolute value of the slope of either function is at least $ \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ over intervals from a few-hundredths to half-a-unit (or so) away from the maximum of each function.

Comment: The exact same reasoning could be used for the function $g(x) = |\sin x| + |\cos x|$, but the maximum of $g(x)$ is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Is this logic right? In this case they don't, but what's stopping $1/2 < \sin^{16} x, \cos^{18} x\leq 1$ at some $x$ and so making their sum exceed 1?

Comment: I realized that would need to be addressed: I have a bit more I'm adding to deal with that.

Comment: I'm still not convinced. We can define a period-$\pi$ curve thus:
$\begin{equation}
f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1-x/1000 &:  0\leq x < 0.1 \\
0.1 &:0.1\leq x<\pi/2-0.1 \\
\pi-2x &:\pi/2-0.05\leq x < \pi/2\\
2x-\pi &:\pi/2\leq x<\pi/2+0.05 \\
0.1 &: \pi/2+0.05\leq x <\pi-0.1\\
1+(x-\pi)/1000 &:\pi-0.1\leq x<\pi
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}$

Also take $g(x) = f(x+\pi/2)$. Note that these functions fit all the criteria, including their values dropping to 0.1 within 0.5 units of their maxima. However, $f(0.07) + g(0.07) = 1.09993 >1$

Comment: I don't doubt that functions can be found that don't descend "fast enough" from their maxima.  I appreciate the significance of the objections you raise.  I am looking for a way to refine the argument by using what is known about powers of the sinusoidal functions without bringing calculus into it.  (Maybe that won't work well enough.)